# Spring Boot: Customize API response based on the User Roles

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to apply some `Authorizations` logic on my controller’s `Methods`
I have an endpoint named `Interview`  that has  `findInterviewById(id)` method which returns an `Interview` object.

The application holds different users [**Owner**, **Recruiters**, **Candidate** and **Guest** ]

Each one can get access to the findInterviewById(id) to read the Interview object and  createInterview(Interview) method to create the interview but each one must read or write the object with restrict mode depending on his Role

Example

- **Recruiter** : can read the entire interview object returned by the `findInterviewById(id)`
- **Guest** : should read only some fields in the interview object returned by the `findInterviewById(id)`

The same thing for `createInterview(Interview)` method , Recruiter can touch all the fields of interview , but Candidate can touch some field

Some solutions said you could duplicate the endpoints but it’s not best practice for a big application

How can i implement this certain authorization logic to achiche this behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use `@JsonSerialize` and implement the required JSON response based on the authority of a user using `serialize(Interview interview, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)`

**Example**

Consider the UserDTO class which is responsible for displaying the list of users. You have to use `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)` at the class level of your DTO or domain.

**DTO/Modal**

```
@JsonSerialize(using = UserDTOSerializer.class)
public class UserDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String login;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @Size(min = 5, max = 254)
    private String email;

    @Size(max = 256)
    private String imageUrl;

    private boolean activated = false;

    //getter-setters and constructors
}
```

**Custom Serializer**

Now let's implement the custom serializer by `@Override` the *serialize()* method, inside it you may get the authority from the security context and customize the response as follows

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import com.learning.jhipster.security.AuthoritiesConstants;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class UserDTOSerializer extends StdSerializer<UserDTO> {

    public UserDTOSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public UserDTOSerializer(Class<UserDTO> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(UserDTO user, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        if(authentication.getAuthorities().toString().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {
            jgen.writeNumberField("id", user.getId());
            jgen.writeStringField("login", user.getLogin());
            jgen.writeBooleanField("activated", user.isActivated());
            jgen.writeStringField("imageUrl", user.getImageUrl());
        }
        jgen.writeStringField("firstName", user.getFirstName());
        jgen.writeStringField("lastName", user.getLastName());
        jgen.writeStringField("email", user.getEmail());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Response**

User logged in as *ROLE_USER* authority will get the following response

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "User",
        "lastName": "User",
        "email": "user@localhost"
    }
]
```

User logged in as *ROLE_ADMIN* will get the following response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "login": "system",
        "activated": true,
        "imageUrl": "",
        "firstName": "System",
        "lastName": "System",
        "email": "system@localhost"
    }
]
```

Comment: You might like to explore more here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous feature of c# and return only specific property based on role. For example

```
If (role == "Guest")
var condidate = new { Id = 1, FirstName = "James", LastName = 
"Bond", location = "noida", skill = ".net" };

else if (role == "Recruiter")
var condidate = new { Id = 1, FirstName = "James", LastName = 
"Bond", location = "noida", skill = ".net", salary = "11LPA",         
expectSalary= "15LPA"};
```

you can write in your business logic. Above could in API methods findInterviewById() or CreateInterview()

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am working on a huge system this will not solve the problem i need to find a way to put this logic away and let without changing  the core code of the application (like using AOP in spring boot application)

Comment: Ok, no idea about spring. this may work in case .net APIs.